# cx_freeze over Python Wand (imagemagick)

Tags: python, imagemagick, cx-freeze, magickwand, wand

Wand needs the ImageMagick library to perform. When I do as they explain [here](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows) my code works just fine on my computer.

However, when I freeze it with `cx_freeze` it misses the extra library. I don't know how to add that library to the zip. I know how to add `.dll` files into the folder, but I can't figure out which `.dll`s Wand needs. When I tried putting all the `.dll`s in the folder it ran but it couldn't convert images.

### Update:

So I included `CORE_RL_wand_*.dll` and `CORE_RL_magick_*.dll` in the folder. Running it I gives me an error:

```
can't start because CORE_RL_bzlib_.dll is missing
```

I added that one and 20 others as it needed them. After that the app starts, but when I try to open and resize and covert an image, I get:

```
wand\resource.py line 223, wand.exception.MissingDelegateError: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat 'pathblah.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552
```

I don't know how to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `CORE_RL_wand_*.dll` and `CORE_RL_magick_*.dll` to the zip.

Comment: so I included those two dlls in the folder. running it I get an error, "can't start because CORE_RL_bzlib_.dll is missing" and I added that one and 20 others as it needed them. After that the app starts but when I try to open and resize and covert an image, I get "wand\resource.py line 223, wand.exception.MissingDelegateError: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat 'pathblah.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/552

Comment: @Kiarash Try adding the entire modules directory as well.

Comment: I tried copying "modules" as a folder or copying all the content in the main folder, neither worked.

Comment: @Kiarash It might be, try that as well.

Comment: nope. it's not working. tried copying all xml files as well as "lib" and "include" folders. how can we get a more descriptive error ?

Comment: can I changed the Wand code locally to get more descriptive errors?